# Criar função para fazer malloc

Tags: c, malloc

tenho a seguinte estrututa

```
    typedef struct{ 
        char *word; 
        int freq; 
       }WordFreq;
```

e tenho no main

```
WordsArray = malloc(sizeof(*WordsArray));
    if(WordsArray==NULL){
        printf("MALLOC doesn't work\n"); 
        free(WordsArray);
        return -1;
    }
```

agora tenho interesse em deixar o main mais limpo, e fazer o malloc através da chamada da seguinte função:

```
WordFreq* firstmalloc( WordFreq* *wordsarray){
    
    *wordsarray = (WordFreq*)malloc(sizeof(*wordsarray));
    if(wordsarray==NULL){
        printf("MALLOC doesn't work\n"); 
        free(wordsarray);
        return NULL;
    }
    return *wordsarray;
}
```

a chamada que faço no main é a seguinte:

```
*WordsArray = firstmalloc(WordsArray);
```

o compilador diz que WordsArray nao esta inicilalizado e na execução do programa da segmentation fault! Como resolver o problema?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Ja resolvi.

Alterei o nome de firstmalloc para arr_strcut_malloc e criei o seguinte algoritmo!

```
void arr_struct_malloc( WordFreq* **wordsarray){

*wordsarray = (WordFreq**)malloc(sizeof(wordsarray));
if(wordsarray==NULL){
    printf("MALLOC doesn't work\n"); 
    free(wordsarray);
    return ;
}
return ;
```

}

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).